# How can I get Toplink generated query by using getTranslatedSQLString?

Tags: java, toplink

So what I'm doing is creating a subquery that gets a list of ID values, then the main query gets all the necessary values and adds ordering.

What I have is this:

```
ReportQuery querySub = new ReportQuery(Predmet.class, generatedExpression);
querySub.addAttribute("m_id");

DatabaseRow row = new DatabaseRow();
querySub.prepareCall(getSession(), row);

// This part is the problem
String sql = querySub.getTranslatedSQLString(getSession(), row);
```

The problem with this code is that it doesn't return TranslatedSQLString, it returns the same result as `querySub.getSQLString()`. Now in all the example code I saw, they either instanced row as a new object or didn't bother to write from where they got the reference but whatever the case, this doesn't work (TopLink version issue?). I'm guessing I need to populate the DatabaseRow object myself, but I can't find any example online.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't manage to find any way to do this by using getTranslatedSQLString. I suppose the DatabaseRow needs to be populated, but I have yet to find the proper way. For now, I'm using "bruteforce" substitution, I "memorize" all of my parameters and do a find/replace on each "?" sign in the query.

Answer (score 0):

you need get session like this:

```
JpaHelper.getDatabaseSession(getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory());
```

The Database that you need is:

```
TypedQuery<T> typedQuery = getEntityManager().createQuery(cq);
DatabaseQuery databaseQuery = typedQuery.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery();
```

So the final example is:

```
Session session = JpaHelper.getDatabaseSession(getEntityManager().getEntityManagerFactory());
DatabaseQuery databaseQuery = null;
if(typedQuery instanceof EJBQueryImpl)
    databaseQuery = ((EJBQueryImpl<T>)typedQuery).getDatabaseQuery();
else
    databaseQuery = typedQuery.unwrap(JpaQuery.class).getDatabaseQuery();
sql = databaseQuery.getTranslatedSQLString(session, databaseQuery.getTranslationRow());
```

That work for me.